# why this is correct: $\det(C+Di)$ is not zero, then there exists some real number $a$ such that $\det(C + a D)$ is not zero

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant

I wonder why the following statement is correct:
supposing $C$ and $D$ are two real matrix, if the determinant of the complex matrix $C + D i  $ is not zero, then there exists some real number $a$ such that $\det(C + a D)$ is not zero?
(where $i$ is the complex unit)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the complex polynomial $p(t)=\det(C+tD)$. If it vanishes on $\mathbb{R}$, then it has infinitely many roots, so it is constant equal to $0$. In particular $p(i)=0$.

**Note:** there is no particular reason to assume $C,D$ to be real. They could be complex. But they need to be square, and of the same size.

**Application:** I suspect this is why you asked the question. If two real square matrices $A,B$ are similar in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then they are similar in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Indeed, the assumption gives us $C,D$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $P=C+iD$ is invertible in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $PA=BP$. This yields $CA=BC$, $DA=BD$, and $\det(C+iD)\neq 0$. By the above argument, there exists $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Q=C+tD$ is invertible. And then $QA=BQ$ is the desired similarity in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I was about to make the same remark...

Comment: wow...thanks a lot...

Comment: @SoManyProblems You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Comment: @SoManyProblems From your records, I see that you have never accepted an answer. Note that it is common usage here, when you are satisfied with an answer, to accept it by clicking on the appropriate button on the left of the answer. Of course, you don't have to, but it is recommended as it somehow closes the question.

Comment: @julien  Thanks for reminding. I didn't notice the "accept" button.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *polynomial* $p(x):=\det(C+xD)$. It is a polynomial, as a big sum of many products with expressions like $c_{ij}+x\cdot d_{ij}$. (In particular, this will have *real* entries.)
We have that $p(i)\ne 0$. It follows that $p\ne 0$, so there is a real number (in fact, almost all) $a$, such that $p(a)\ne 0$.